# Simple select statement when member is involved

Tags: sql, vb.net, vba, ibm-midrange

I am sure this is as simple as a question can get but I have been stumped on it so figured that I would ask in hope of a quick response.  Using an OLEDB connection I want to do a select statement but for the table I am selecting from, a table member also has to be there too which seems to be messing up my results.

Normally I would write to get the column "col1":

```
SELECT lib1.table.col1 FROM lib1.table
```

For the table I need the information from, the table has a "submember".  From what I have gathered the syntax is something like this:

```
SELECT lib1.table(submember).col1 FROM lib1.table(submember)
```

The problem is that the results are giving me every column within the table, not just my "col1" data.  I hope that this is well explained for what I am looking for.  Thanks ahead of time for anyone who helps.

Comment: why the tags for vb.net and vba? These are two completely different languages / technologies...

Comment: Those are where the OLEDB connection is being made

Comment: So you have a VB.NET application and a VBA application, both with the same select statement?

Comment: To be honest, I have never seen this submember syntax. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Me either being why I am here lol.  It is an AS400 database

Comment: Can you provide more detail - this doesn't make sense.

Comment: try using bracket notation instead of dots and parenthesis. so `lib1[table][submember][col1]`

Comment: Within the table itself, exists submembers (such as seperate tables themselves in a way) so the submember item must be identified first. Inside each of these subtables exist columns like any other SQL table.  Don't ask me why our system is set up this way but it's just how it is.

Comment: Nope. I tried that and it still returns the whole table.  Also something that may help (although it hasn't for me so far..) is that we also have a tool called "IBM ShowCase Query" that helps us create queries (even though I need this in an actual program) and it is able to correctly pull just the selected column. The SQL statement that it uses is the following: SELECT "$7ITM" FROM CPJDDTA81.F5548311:SCHEDULING SCHEDULING I have tried the same syntax within my OLEDB connection and it doesn't recongnize the ":" so I changed the syntax to CPJDDTA81.F5548311(SCHEDULING) which at least pulls data

Comment: I just tried "lib1[table][submember][col1]" and it still returned all columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create alias library.aliasname for library.table(member)

Then do the select on the alias

Comment: I do not have access on my server to create tables.  Any other ideas?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is the only option. I don't know what 6.1 or 7.1 can offer.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing (more or less). Thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create an [ALIAS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzhcalias.htm) in `QTEMP`:

```
CREATE ALIAS QTEMP.TABLE FOR LIB1.TABLE (SUBMEMBER)
```

And then query through the temporarily created alias:

```
SELECT COL1 FROM QTEMP.TABLE
```

It will be automatically removed when your connection ends.

Comment: Agreed, create these kinds of temporary `alias`es in `QTEMP` (what amounts to a per-job, full-authorization scratch directory).  If your connection job doesn't have access to that, you're going to have all sorts of trouble anyways...